# C# Query can change independently in context

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, orm

I have a difficult question. I have seen that the number of the record in a query can change without re-run the same query.
The code below shows the scenario:

```
using (var db = new MyContext()) {
    var query = from e in db.Entities select e;

    //here the query.Count is equals to 100 for example

    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    //after some times the db has been populated

    //here the query.Count is equals to 200 for example without run again the query
}
```

My question is: why this behaviour? why it seems to be an automatic binding between the query result and the data layer? Entity framework works in background in order to update the query result?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but I believe the answer is [lazy loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386920(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that with an IQueryable, thanks to [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the query will be evaluated and executed against the database every time that you enumerate it, that is, when you run `.Count()`, `.ToList()` etc.

If in doubt, use a profiler, such as [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) or [EF Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf) to understand exactly when you are hitting the database.